# In WPF, can the word-wrapping of a TextBlock use the text of inline Runs to generate breaks between words instead of in their middles?

Tags: wpf, word-wrap, textblock

In WPF, if you have inline Runs inside of a text block, word-wrapping works on a per-letter basis. I'd like it to use the default functionality that is word-by-word wrapping, i.e:

```
lorem
ipsum
```

instead of

```
lorem ip
sum
```

I'm generating the inline Runs programmatically, code snippet as follows:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock() {
    TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
};

foreach (string part in parts)
{
    tb.Inlines.Add(new Run(part));
}
```

The Runs are woven inside the TextBlock with InlineUIContainers that contain Images. If I set the Text property of the Textblock instead of using Runs it works normally, but I can't do that and weave in images with the text. Very open to alternative solutions as well.

Comment: Have you tried doing `tb.Inlines.Add(part)`

Comment: @erotavlas That worked! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[erotavlas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1462656/erotavlas) suggested I use `tb.Inlines.Add(part)` instead and it works precisely as requested.